# How do I debug a failed commit to github?

Tags: git, github, dvcs

I'm new to git and github.  My first commit of my project has failed.  I'm probably doing something stupid.

I'd welcome anyone pointing out the stupid thing that I'm probably doing, but the worthier question is this: how can I find out what's going on here?

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:andy-twosticks/flungle.git

$ git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/andy/.ssh/id_rsa': 
ERROR: andy-twosticks/flungle.git doesn't exist. Did you enter it correctly?
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ git remote add origin git@github.com:andy-twosticks/Flungle.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

$ git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/andy/.ssh/id_rsa': 
ERROR: andy-twosticks/flungle.git doesn't exist. Did you enter it correctly?
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Looks like it's working for you now, at least I can see your commits on Github.

Comment: As a matter of record, the actual problem was caused by case: I'd named the github repo "Flungle" and git, apparently, is not case sensitive.  The real question remains, however: how could I figure out what was going on here?   Ta.

Comment: I think git is case sensitive, that's why your first push attempt failed (your repo was named Flungle.git and not flungle.git). The second push attempt failed because you cannot re-add another remote location with the same name (``origin``) - you should have used ``git remote set-url origin git@github.com:andy-twosticks/Flungle.git`` in the third step to change the URL the remote is pointing to.

Comment: I would have tested everything step by step. Firstly, I would have checked the connectivity via ssh as described [here](http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/). `$ ssh -T git@github.com`. Secondly, I would have checked the spelling maybe - easy to say afterwards ...

Comment: Thanks to everyone, as usual -- always helpful...